# What is the specification for max DOCSIS TLV length?

Tags: docsis

I'm trying to find the specification for a DOCSIS CM config file TLV `length` field. I'm assuming the length field is a single octet, which would mean the length would be `2^8-1` bytes long. However, I have some code that seems to imply a max length of `2^8+1`. So I want to know if the code is wrong, and I can't find in the DOCSIS specs any details on TLV implementation details (such as the size of the length field). I imagine that exists somewhere, and I probably missed it… Also, I seem to remember that some TLV implementations will split a value to the next TLV, so if the previous TLV is the same tag and the max length that the length field will allow, then it is assumed that the TLV is a continuation of the previous TLV, and the value should be concatenated... Don't think DOCSIS does that though, does it?

Comment: "_I'm assuming the length field id a single octet_" You know what they say about assume :) It is really dependent on the Type and some Lengths are one byte, and some are two bytes. Both the DOCSIS 3.1 and DOCSIS 4.0 specifications are out there and available from a simple search. Cable Labs maintains the specifications.

Comment: The *type* and *length* fields also use some space...